# JavaFX TableView change selected cell colour

Tags: css, javafx, tableview, selection, tablecell

I have a JavaFX TableView and a ListView and they both use custom cell factories. In particular I have overridden updateItem method in order to bind a particular CSS class based on cell value.

This is part of my CSS file:

```
.tissueCell {
    -fx-text-fill: #F5AD11;
}

.tissueCell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: #F5AD11;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.significantDataCell {
    -fx-background-color: yellow;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}

.significantDataCell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}
```

For the ListView everything work flawlessly: text is displayed with the proper colour and when the cell is selected the text becomes white and the background is filled with proper colour.

I am experiencing problems with the TableView instead. When unselected the text in the cell is displayed with the chosen colour, but when the cell is selected the background is filled with default JavaFX colour for selected table cells background and the text colour remains #F5AD11 (it does not become white).

The same happens with TableCells that use .significantDataCell class. Cells are displayed properly with yellow background and black text, but when selected nothing changes, not event the background this time.

Any ideas? I did a lot of research but couldn't find any working solution.

Comment: What selection mode are you using for your `TableView`. Do you have `cellSelectionEnabled` set to `true`, or are you just selecting by row?

Comment: Thank you, you put me on the right path! I am a FX newbie and I did not consider to enable singleCellSelection (which is better than row selection for my application). By enabling cellSelection everything works just fine even with TableView. Just out of curiosity, what should I have done if I needed to keep row selection enabled? (I use SelectionMode.SINGLE)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, `TableView`s do not allow selection of individual cells, but allow selection of rows. Thus the selector `.table-cell:selected` never matches any cell in the default selection mode. In this case, you would need

```
.table-row-cell:selected .table-cell {
    /* style definitions */
}
```

or in your scenario

```
.table-row-cell:selected .tissue-cell {
    -fx-background-color: #F5AD11;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
```

etc.

If you allow the table to use cell selection, by calling

```
myTableView.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
```

then individual cells become selected on mouse click (etc), and so your original CSS will work.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the difference between row and cell selection! This finally solved my problem as well – although for me `.table-row:selected` did not work but `.table-row-cell:selected`.

Comment: Yes, it should be `table-row-cell`: thanks for pointing that out. I'll fix it.